# Unable to log from Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, foreach, log4j, spark-streaming

I am trying to log output of spark streaming as shown in the code below

```
dStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  if (rdd.count() > 0) {
    @transient lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)  
    log.info("Process Starting")

      rdd.foreach { item =>

     log.info("Output :: "+item._1 + "," + item._2 + "," + System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
 }
```

The code is executed on a yarn cluster using the following command

```
./bin/spark-submit --class "StreamingApp" --files file:/home/user/log4j.properties  --conf  "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/log4j.properties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/user/log4j.properties" --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 4g --executor-memory 2g --executor-cores 1 /home/user/Abc.jar
```

When i view the logs from the yarn cluster, I can find the logs written before foreach i.e. `log.info("Process Starting")` but the logs inside foreach  are not printing.

I had also tried creating a separate serializable class as below

```
    object LoggerObj extends Serializable{

        @transient lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
   }
```

and using the same inside foreach as follows

```
dStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  if (rdd.count() > 0) {

    LoggerObj.log.info("Process Starting")

      rdd.foreach { item =>

     LoggerObj.log.info("Output :: "+item._1 + "," + item._2 + "," + System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
 }
```

but still the same issue, only the logs outside of foreach are being printed.

The log4j.properties is given below

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,stdout,FILE
log4j.rootCategory=INFO,FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/tmp/Rt.log
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=500MB
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.logger.Holder=INFO,FILE
```

Comment: You need to look in your *Worker nodes*, you'll find a `/tmp/Rt.log` in each of them.

Comment: Foreach is an action. When your pipeline runs, look for the stdout/stderr link of driver in 'executors' tab of Spark UI where executor id is 'driver'. Check for the logs there and let me know if you can find there.

Comment: @RakeshRakshit I can only find the logs written before foreach i.e. log.info("Process Starting") not the logs inside foreach.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i have checked the worker nodes but couldnot find /tmp/Rt.log file

Comment: Do you have permission to write there? Is your `log4j.properties` properly set in the worker nodes?

Comment: YuvalItzchakov yes I have permission. I haven't put log4j.properties file in each node but uploaded it during spark-submit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by putting "log4j.properties" file under each worker nodes.

Comment: Are you able to print the logs inside foreach to unix file loacton ? I tried and able to see the log to stderr in spark driver. But not able to capture the log to UNIX file. Could you please suggest

Comment: Yes by following the above approach logs are generated under each worker node on the location /tmp/Rt.log, as given in the log4j.properties file

Comment: How did you pass log4j propert to each worker node ?

Comment: Created a new object called "Holder" in which I have initialized a variable "log" as "lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)". This is then used in different codes for logging e.g. Holder.log.info("RDD Size :: " + rdd.count())

Comment: i did same, But the logger is printing the result on spark driver (Spark application UI ->Spark Job name ->Executors->logs- > STDERR) . I am trying to print the log from streaming job (from inside of rdd.foreach loop)  to unix file at unix location.